# How do you turn a .png file into a 2-d matrix?

Tags: c, png

I am working on a project for a Bio-medical Imaging course (Note: it is a non-programming course, so asking for programming help is not cheating.  Asking for conceptual help with planning would be cheating.) where I need to manipulate an image using different mathematical transforms.  I am writing in C so it can be as fast as possible.  I have finished the code for the mathematical transforms, but I have realized that I do not know how to turn a grayscale .png file into a 2-d matrix/array to compute with, and I do not know how to display a .png file in C.  Can anyone help me?

I'm trying to turn the "image.png" image into a 2d array where each entry in the array has a value between 0 - 255 and corresponds with each pixel in "image.png".  I also want to turn a 2d array where each entry corresponds to a pixel in the image and has a value between 0 - 255 into a new "image_two.png" file.

I'm a somewhat new programmer.  I have a solid base in python programming, but C is new for me.  I have done a lot of research and I have found a lot of people talking about using ["this library"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pnglite/) or ["that library"](http://lodev.org/lodepng/), or also ["this library"](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), but how do I use a downloaded library in C?  It's unfamiliar territory for me as a python programmer :(

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

To reiterate:

- How do you read a grayscale .png image as a 2-d array/matrix in C?
- How do you display a 2-d array/matrix as a grayscale image in C?
- <strike>How do you use a downloaded library in C code (specifically for the two questions above)?</strike> I found out how to use these libraries.

EDIT: I am still having trouble figuring out how to create a grayscale 2d array out of a .png file and how to make a .png file out of a grayscale 2d matrix.  Can anyone else help?

Comment: Learning how to use basic compiler tools is normally outside of scope of SO.

Comment: Side note: "am writing in C so it can be as fast as possible" if you don't know the language may be very challenging. You may be way better to use language you already know and get code working correctly with acceptable speed rather than  learning brand new language and get code that work very fast but completely wrong (at least for some time till you learn new language enough).

Comment: He's learning, and there's no better way to learn than by trying to write something and solving problems you encounter. Give him a break.

Comment: The code that I have written for my mathematical transforms take 1.5 hours in python, and take 2 minutes tops in C.  I understand the logic in C well enough to have significantly faster code, I just need a way to get the .png file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install a library in Linux, typically you will use the package manager. For example, in Debian (this includes Ubuntu) you might do:

```
$ apt-cache search libpng
```

You'll decide which package to install based on the results of running this command and then you will run

```
$ sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

This command will likely install `png.h` in a location that is already included in gcc's search path. This means that to use `png.h` in your program, all you have to do is include it.

```
#include <png.h>
```

Skip to chapter 3 in the [libpng manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.4.0-manual.pdf) for a walkthrough on reading a png file.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped, I have the libraries and I can use them now.  I still haven't yet figured out how to turn a grayscale .png file into a 2d matrix/array and vice versa.  I've started reading the manual and it has a terrible lot of information, most of it irrelevant for me.  Do you have any short code that I could use to help me avoid reading most of the manual?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but a little googling came up with this.  http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html

Comment: It has helped me, because I have the library and I know how to use it now, but I still haven't figured out how to do the code snippet that I need.  The manual is complicated and research is not giving me good results :( I need to write something that does...
given "image.png"...
I end up with: image_matrix = (a 2d array of the grayscale pixels of "image.png")

Comment: Did you see the link I posted three comments ago? See `read_png_file()` and `process_file()` for an example of pixel-level access.

Comment: When I go to compile the code, I get a lot of "undefined references".  For example:
`pngimage.c:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to 'png_sig_cmp';
pngimage.c:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to 'png_create_read_struct';
pngimage.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to 'png_create_info_struct';
pngimage.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to 'png_init_io';
pngimage.c:(.text+0x211): undefined reference to 'png_set_sig_bytes'`

Comment: Apparently the library is not being loaded, so you're going to have to modify your call to gcc. Something like `gcc -o runme pngimage.c -lpng`.  If it turns out that libpng is not in gcc's search path, you'll have to manually specify it with the -L option as in `gcc -o runme pngimage.c -L/path/to/png.h -lpng`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a more general purpose image handling library and you might find it easier to use.  I recommend FreeImage http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/.  See the pixel access section of the manual to get access to the pixel data.  You can then work with it directly or copy it into your own matrix.